# Magento2 - product bulk assign to website

Tags: magento2, product, multi-website

I am about to setup a different "website" in my Magento 2 Shop. I want to assign all products to that Website and copy the data from one specific store-view within the base-website. Is there a solution to create this in bulk ( SQL maybe ? )

Did anyone already accomplished a task like that?

---

**TLDR - short explanation ( I want to ):**

> • Copy the product data from website1 - storeview1
>
> • Assign the product to website2
>
> • Assign the storeview data from website1 storeview1 to website2
>   storeview2

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via magento interface itself

1. In **product grid** select all products you want to add in the new website.
   [image: select all products]
2. Then from mass action select **update attributes**.
   [image]
3. You will get a new interface select **websites** from left tab. In **Add Product To Websites** select the website you want to assign.
   [image: choose website]

You can do both operation add and remove products from that interface.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer :) - Is it possible to copy the storeview data that way or does it copy the default ( admin ) data ?

Comment: I have not tested that. But I guess it should give you a option or else it will copy the admin data

Comment: sadly no options to copy storeview-data :/